# Group the column value based on selective rows for an id

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table which have 4 dimensions for a foreignid.
I want to find unique combination based on 2 dimensions.

```
TABLE1
-----------------------------
ID  NAME    VALUE   TABLE2ID
-----------------------------
1   TYPE    10      1       
2   DIR     IN      1
3   STATE   MA      1
4   COUNT   100     1
5   TYPE    10      2       
6   DIR     IN      2
7   STATE   SA      2
8   COUNT   200     2
9   TYPE    20      3       
10  DIR     OUT     3
11  STATE   MA      3
12  COUNT   300     3
-----------------------------
```

Here, I want the TABLE2IDs based on the combination of TYPE and DIR rows which is unique.

So, here if you aggregate the row values based on TYPE and DIR you will get

```
-----------------------------
TYPE    DIR TABLE2ID
-----------------------------
10      IN  1
10      IN  2
20      OUT 3
-----------------------------
```

Note:
The above question is answered

> **Additional Question related to this.**

I have another table which have the count for table2 id based on hour.

I want to group all the count for all hours in a day for unique combination in table1(Don't worry about table 2 structure).

```
TABLE3
-----------------------------
ID  TIME    COUNT   TABLE2ID
-----------------------------
1   2016101601  10      1       
2   2016101602  20      1
3   2016101603  30      1       
4   2016101604  40      1
5   2016101601  10      2       
6   2016101602  20      2
7   2016101603  30      2       
8   2016101604  40      2
9   2016101601  10      3       
10  2016101602  20      3
11  2016101603  30      3       
12  2016101604  40      3
-----------------------------
```

Here, I want the output be grouped based on unique value of table 1 according to type and name(regardless of table2id)

```
----------------------------------
TYPE    DIR     DATE        COUNT
----------------------------------
10      IN      20161016    200
20      OUT     20161016    100
---------------------------------
```

Comment: The above output can be achieved using the following query.
Thanks to MT0

 select
  dimension.type, dimension.dir, trunc(table3.date), sum(count) as count
 from
  table3,
  (select *
  from ( select name, value, table2id from table1 )
  pivot  ( max(value) for name in ( 'type' as type, 'dir' as dir ) )
  ) dimension
 where
  table3.table2id =  dimension.table2id
 group by
  dimension.type, dimension.dir, trunc(table3.date);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [PIVOT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id, name, value, table2id ) AS
SELECT  1, 'TYPE',  '10',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'DIR',   'IN',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'STATE', 'MA',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'COUNT', '100', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'TYPE',  '10',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'DIR',   'IN',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'STATE', 'SA',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'COUNT', '200', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'TYPE',  '20',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'DIR',   'OUT', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'STATE', 'MA',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'COUNT', '300', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT name, value, table2id FROM table1 )
PIVOT  ( MAX(value) FOR name IN ( 'TYPE' AS type, 'DIR' AS DIR ) );
```

**Output**:

```
TABLE2ID TYPE DIR
-------- ---- ---
       1 10   IN
       2 10   IN
       3 20   OUT
```

Or as an alternative:

```
SELECT table2id,
       MAX( CASE WHEN name = 'TYPE' THEN value END ) AS type,
       MAX( CASE WHEN name = 'DIR'  THEN value END ) AS dir
FROM   table1
GROUP BY table2id;
```

Comment: Thanks dude.

Could you please review my additional question related to this

Comment: `INNER JOIN` the result above with the result from `SELECT table2id, TRUNC( time ) AS "DATE", SUM( "COUNT" ) AS "COUNT" FROM table3 GROUP BY table2id, TRUNC( time )`. However, its not clear how you get the count value.

Answer (score 0):

You could join two subqueries, one that selects the types and one that selects the dirs for the same id:

```
SELECT type, dir, a.table2id
FROM   (SELECT value AS type, table2id
        FROM   table1
        WHERE  name = 'TYPE') a
JOIN   (SELECT value AS dir, table2id
        FROM   table1
        WHERE  name = 'DIR') b ON a.table2id = b.table2id
```